# How to add single quote "'" to javascript string

Tags: javascript, string

So many related questions out there, but none satisfyingly answered using javascript (no jQuery).

I wish to add quotes around a variable in a string I'm building.  My string itself should contain single quotes within it like so:

`'{'a'}'`

I can get: 
`'{a}'`

When I try to add single quotes around the key  `a`  I get:

`'{\'a\'}'`

I've used both of the following syntax with the same result. 
 Any suggestions??

`concat('\'','a','\'')`

`'\''+'a'+'\''`

See line 39 of this code: https://repl.it/@mike_butak/LiveForHisPleasureHeReallyIsThere

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code where you set the variable equal to a string, and also where/how are you seeing the output of your variable?  Web console, alert(), console.log() ?

Comment: `var b = "'" + a + "'";`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
console.log("'{'a'}'")
```

To expand on this, when you are building the string, just use `"` around the string, and `'` within the string.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  That'd work except it's just logging it instead of returning it.

Comment: Ah, if only it were that simple.  I have to have a very dynamic construction process because it'll be used to create a large variety of different strings.

Comment: Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Having a hard time replicating your issue! See:

```js
   var temp = '\'{\'a\'}\'';
   console.log('s' + temp + 's');
```

I'd definitely recommend demonstrating the issue you are asking about in a console print or in a readily available editor online before posting a question!

As per your comment, updating to make it part of a variable assignment. Still unclear what the issue is!

Comment: It might be the difference that I'm returning the value as part of a string instead of console.logging it.  Oh I just saw your recommendation to demonstrate using an online editor.  Let me see what I can do.  Thanks Peter!

Comment: Ok, the issue is on line 39 of this code: https://repl.it/@mike_butak/LiveForHisPleasureHeReallyIsThere

Comment: Just to show the same code in variable assignment, I updated! I'll check out your source in a sec!

Comment: I hope my answer helps! I tried to check your code, but I still don't quite track. Where do you expect there to be apostrophes?

Comment: I'm sorry Peter but when I visit the link now it says repl not found!  I did change the name of it so that your changes wouldn't affect my working copy.  I'm sorry but I've lost what you did in doing so.

Comment: But it's ok, I think the test is actually looking for double quotes, which I can add easily.